# How to get all diagonal from an array of words in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, math

I have an array in Ruby

```
words = ["horses", "follow", "useful", "offset"]
```

Reference:

```
h o r s e s
f o l l o w
u s e f u l
o f f s e t
```

I want to get a list of all its diagonals like this.
Here is want I expect in result:

```
["o", "uf", "fsf", "hoes", "olfe", "rlut", "sol", "ew", "s"]
```

Would be helpful if anyone can help me a bit on this. Thanks

Comment: What did you try, and what is not working?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to accomplish this tbh. Also since its 4x6 and can be dynamic too.

Comment: perhaps you should first forget about Ruby for a few seconds. How would you describe this in mathematics. If it is too hard to come up with a formula, it might be worth first trying to determine the indices of the above example, and then aim to generalize.

Comment: For the element at location `i,j` let `t=i-j`. Then the element at location `p,q` is on the same main diagonal if and only if `p-q=t`. Varying `t` produces all main diagonals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
words = ["horses", "follow", "useful", "offset"]

words.reverse.each_with_index.map{|s,i| " " * i + s }.inject(Array.new(words.size + words.last.size-1,"")) do |a,s| 
  s.chars.each_with_index do |c,i| 
    a[i] = c + a[i]
  end
  a
end.map(&:strip)
# => ["o", "uf", "fsf", "hoes", "olfe", "rlut", "sol", "ew", "s"]
```

At first `words.reverse.each_with_index.map{|s,i| " " * i + s }` builds array with whitespace offset:

```
offset
 useful
  follow
   horses
```

Inject creates array  of empty strings and inside main block each string chars are prepended to proper array element